# posting automation

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I use Joomla. I could use something other than Joomla if you recommend.

The scenario is: I want my website to automatically take new articles from various news websites (as soon as they are published) and post them on my website.

Or at least I want a mechanism of easing the process of taking articles from tens of websites and posting them on my website.

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am making a Joomla website, and I want to automate posting of articles from other websites on my website, what is the best way to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712936/i-am-making-a-joomla-website-and-i-want-to-automate-posting-of-articles-from-ot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built in core function in 1.5. You can display RSS feeds in module positions or as a component.

You can find instructions here - http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_display_an_RSS_feed%3F